# Is it ok to do wudhu instead of taking a bath?

Tags: wudu, taharah, ghusl

I have a friend she has a phobia of bathing whenever she has to take a bath her cousin helps her in that because while bathing she suffers from anxiety attacks which makes it not possible for her to take a bath alone ....now her cousin is not available for 1 day can she just make a wudhu instead of a ghusl till her cousin returns and helps her in taking a bath?

Comment: As Ibraheem Muhammad's answer says, she only needs to do ghusl when it is required because of greater ritual impurity. Also note that private parts are awrah between people of the same gender, so her cousin should not be able to look at them.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model i.e. what is on- and what is off-topic here I suggest you to take the [Tour] and check our [help].

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the level of her ritual impurity.  If she has had sexual  intercourse (with or without ejaculation), or if she is menstruating, or if she is suffering from postpartum bleeding (after childbirth) then she is in a state of major ritual impurity (janabat) and she is obligated to make ghusl. In the case of menstruation and postpartum bleeding the sister is obligated to make ghusl after they cease. May Allahu ta alaa ease her anxiety and help her perfect her Deen.